# onClick is not working on Popper component in Material-UI Tooltip

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popper.js

The intended behavior is to go to another page when tooltip is clicked. to achieve this functionality I provided the onClick prop for the `PopperProps` object.

Below is my code:

```
interface Props extends TooltipProps{}

const CustomTooltip : React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { arrow, ...classes } = useStylesBootstrap();
  const [arrowRef, setArrowRef] = React.useState<HTMLSpanElement | null>(null);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("clicked");
    window.location.replace('/info/contact-us');
  };

  return (
    <Tooltip
      classes={classes}
      PopperProps={{
        style: { border: "1px red solid" },
        onClick: handleClick,
        popperOptions: {
          modifiers: {
            arrow: {
              enabled: Boolean(arrowRef),
              element: arrowRef,
            },
          },
        },
      }}
      {...props}
      title={(
        <>
          {props.title}
          <span className={arrow} ref={setArrowRef} />
        </>
        )}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Your error message (and your `Props` interface) look like you are passing a `click` prop to `CustomTooltip` and then passing that through (via `{...props}`) to `Tooltip`. This is unrelated to what you are doing with `PopperProps`.

Comment: Thanks @RyanCogswell, the error went away but still `onClick` is not working. I also edited my question.

Comment: You are putting the `onClick` on a [div that isn't part of the presentation of the tooltip](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui/src/Popper/Popper.js#L211). The div you would want to target is [this one](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui/src/Tooltip/Tooltip.js#L509) which there isn't any way to provide additional props to. I think you might be better off using [Popper](https://material-ui.com/components/popper/) directly rather than `Tooltip`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell So it seems I need to fork material-ui if I want to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Forking Material-UI sounds like a fairly extreme solution. One option would be to put more html within the `title` and put the click handler in there.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I tried that as well. doesn't work either and I don't know why?

Comment: The way Tooltip is implemented, if the display of the tooltip is triggered by hovering over a different element, it isn't easy to click in the Tooltip without the Tooltip going away (because of no longer hovering over the element that triggered the tooltip). I'm not sure what you're exact use case is, but, again, I think leveraging Popper instead of Tooltip will give you more control over these aspects.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Actually I control the tooltip with a boolean, when the condition is met, the flag will be true and tooltip shows. so it's not hard to click on it. it's really weird. BTW Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the `interactive` prop for the `Tooltip`. When `interactive` is not specified, `Tooltip` [disables pointer events](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui/src/Tooltip/Tooltip.js#L81) (so click doesn't do anything), but `pointer-events` is set to `auto` when [interactive is true](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui/src/Tooltip/Tooltip.js#L85). The `interactive` prop also prevents the `Tooltip` from immediately closing as you move the mouse from the triggering element to the `Tooltip`.

Here is a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";

export default function SimpleTooltips() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Tooltip
        interactive
        title={
          <div onClick={() => console.log("clicked tooltip text")}>Delete</div>
        }
      >
        <IconButton aria-label="delete">
          <DeleteIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Interactive Tooltip]

Comment: Thanks for your time sir.